# Where can I find the source code of packages/modules?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I would like to look at the code of functions defined in modules, such as Data.List or Data.Map.

I can import Data.List module with

```
import Data.List
```

and then I can use the functions `nub` or `sort`.

I would like to know where I can find these functions to look at their code.

**In which directory are the modules installed by default?**

PS: Windows 8.1, I installed Haskell Platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That directory contains compiled modules, so you wouldn't be able to read the source there.

What you can do is to find your function in [online documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort) and then click "Source" on the right.

Comment: Where can I find the directory with the compiled modules?

Comment: It generally depends on what system you are running and what tool you used to build them. `stack` place stuff in STACK_ROOT and ~/.stack/snapshots, for instance.

Comment: My installation is using `cabal`, on Windows 8.1. I tried to use Windows search with some keywords, but I did not get any result.

Comment: cabal install into `/Users/user/.cabal`, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

As [@arrowd notes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45775290/1498178),

> That directory contains compiled modules, so you wouldn't be able to
>   read the source there.

The [GHC repo](http://git.haskell.org/ghc.git) (and [its Github mirror](https://github.com/ghc/ghc)) can be directly browsed, but there is an easier way:

1. **Use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) to find the package where the module/function resides**

   Note that [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) are *case-sensitive*. (It's best to look up modules with their capitalized names.)

   A query for `sort` in [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) yields  a list similar to the one below. [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) has a slightly different style, but the basics are the same (mostly because it uses Hoogle for lookup). The lines in green under the result headings show the name(s) of the containing

   (1) package(s) (in small caps) and

   (2) module(s) (capitalized).

   There can be multiple functions with the same name, but the module and package name helps to choose the right one.

   [image: Hoogle lookup]
2. **Click on the function/module name**
3. **Click on "#Source"**

   [image: Hackage lookup]